# Unary and binary arithmetic operations in Prolog

Tags: binary, prolog, successor-arithmetics

I am trying to do  unary and binary arithmetic operations in Prolog.

unary numbers are defined as `bot=0` and `s(X)=x+1`, for example *3* is `s(s(s(bot)))`.

binary numbers are represented as a series of `Z`s and `O`s when `Z` is the digit *zero* and `O` the digit *one* going from least significant bit to the most significant bit. for example *4* is `z(z(o(bot)))`.

and it all goes well when I am using predicates of the form `power(z(o(bot),z(o(bot)),Result).`
but when I am trying something like `power(X,z(o(bot)),z(o(o(bot))) ).` it collapses.

```
suc(bot,o(bot)).
suc(o(X),z(Res)):-suc(X,Res).
suc(z(X),o(Res)):-X=Res.

add(bot,X,X).
add(s(X),Y,Res):-add(X,s(Y),Res).
add(X,Y,Res):-suc(A,X),
    suc(Y,B),
    add(A,B,Res).

multiply(bot,_,bot).
multiply(_,bot,bot).
multiply(X,Y,Res):-suc(A,X),
        multiply(A,Y,NewRes),
        add(Y,NewRes,Res).
multiply(s(X),Y,Res):-multiply(X,Y,NewRes),
    add(Y,NewRes,Res).

power(_,bot,s(bot)).
power(X,o(bot),X).
power(X,s(Y),Res):-power(X,Y,NewRes),
    multiply(X,NewRes,Res).
power(X,Y,Res):-suc(A,Y),
        power(X,A,NewRes),
        multiply(X,NewRes,Res).
```

Comment: Suggestion: stick to unary first. Binary is tricky if you want to ensure reversibility

Comment: unary works fine. forgot to mention.
the problem is the binary and maybe the pattern matching between binary and unary

Comment: @ZevSheleg: Mixing them within your definitions is next-to-impossible. Rather define them separately.

Comment: the whole idea of this is to rely on pattern matching.
and it works well when I am trying to compute a power but not a log

Comment: I did not aware that's called church encoding. anyway I am just using it to represent numbers. the problem is why it can compute only expressions of the form power(num1,num2,X) and not power(X,num1,num2)

Comment: As long as you have 0 and s(X) this is called [tag:successor-arithmetics] or Peano numbers

Comment: Prolog unification is symbolical but you want `s(bot)` and `o(bot)` etc. to unify. you could define your own predicate `same_number(Unary, Binary)` an use *it* instead of plain unification.

Comment: @WillNess: except that this will affect reversibility

Comment: @false re "Erlang tag does not know Prolog fully and highlights some goals but not all of them in a uniform manner" is of course correct, but still the improvement to readability is enormous, i.e. the loss of readability *without it* is enormous. plain dense Prolog code like here is a near unreadable wall of text for me. YMMV.